# 5 year survival rate chi squared test

Tags: r

I am using the survival package for a population with two subgroups. I need the 5 year KM survival percentage for each group. I got this value from:

```
summary(survfit(Surv(survtime, vital)~subgroup)), time = 60) #in months
```

However, I also wanted to run a chisq test on the two five year survival rates. Is there an easy way to run this test using the survival package?

Thank you for any advice and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way to go about it (buyer beware), but here is an example using the `aml` dataset included as example data with the `survival` package.

```
library(survival)
amlsurv <- with(aml,survfit(Surv(time,status) ~ x))
summary(amlsurv ,time=20)
```

Which results in, for `time=20`:

```
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x)

                x=Maintained 
        time       n.risk      n.event
      20.000        7.000        3.000 ...

                x=Nonmaintained 
        time       n.risk      n.event
      20.000        6.000        5.000 ...
```

Both of these options fail using the `survdiff` function:

```
survdiff(summary(aml,time=20))
survdiff(aml,time=20)
```

Now try limiting to 20 days manually:

```
aml$status.20 <- aml$status
# set 'deaths' with a time greater than 20 to be 'survivors'
aml$status.20[aml$status == 1 & aml$time > 20] <- 0
amlsurv <- (Surv(aml$time,aml$status.20) ~ aml$x)
summary(survfit(amlsurv))
# results are the same as above, Maintained=3 events,Nonmaintained=5 events
```

Now you can get your results for the 20 days limit comparing the two groups:

```
survdiff(amlsurv)
Call:
survdiff(formula = amlsurv)

                     N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
aml$x=Maintained    11        3      4.3     0.392     0.874
aml$x=Nonmaintained 12        5      3.7     0.455     0.874

 Chisq= 0.9  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.35
```

Comment: Thanks! I went forward and tried to write a custom function to solve it. But I was also wary that I made a mistake. I'll check out this method once I get off work and see if it's consistent with what I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `survdiff()`:

```
s.fit <- survfit(Surv(survtime, vital)~subgroup)
survdiff(s.fit)
```